# How to handle multiple form submissions within content slider js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a content slider with multiple html  tags which represent each tab. And within each tab has a form. Say, when I submit a form from tab2 , it reloads the page and goes back to first tab.

What I would like to see is it should redirect back to where the form was submitted.

Need Help :-)

First Tab
[image: first tab]
Second Tab
[image: second tab]

Answer (score -1):

You have to track the submit button been pressed by the user. Let say if the Button is from `Tab2`, you saved the variable `clicked='tab2'`.

And put the JS on the load of the form to display the same form.

Comment: You will loose all the variables when u load the page. Store last selection value into cookies or post to form or add to querysting

Comment: How can you loose the variables on request/response cycle? All the variables from the `form` will be available on the action and you can set the request attributes or parameters on the response.